# AngularJS and bower issue

Tags: angularjs, bower

I'm getting this uncaught syntax error and I have tried some of the solutions I've seen yet no solution, trying to set up AngularJS to display my HTML pages, but when I run it in the browser, it shows the following error:

> uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in angular.js:1 in the console.

My **app.js**:

```js
 angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
    angular.module('app').config([
        '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: '/app/home/index.html',
                    controller: 'HomeController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                })
                .when('/about', {
                    templateUrl: '/app/about/index.html',
                    controller: 'AboutController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                })
        }
    ])
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
        <base href="/">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" ng-controller="LabController as vm">
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <i class="far fa-lg fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>{{"Angular is working"}}
                </div>
                <div class="navbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
        <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="app/app.js"></script></script>
        <script src="app/HomeController.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495743/node-angular-app-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: Which version of AngularJS / ui.router are you using?

Comment: Angular 1.6.9 and same version for angular-route

Comment: @JackRyan that solution did not work for me

Comment: It is bit difficult to identify the actual issue with the code that you have posted. Please create a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/) to reproduce the issue, and provide the link here.

Comment: That's probably 404 error. Open the developer tools and check the network tab for error

Comment: @AlonEitan I've checked it but it's not the issue

Comment: @Thangadurai here is the plunkr link https://plnkr.co/edit/fR6ckHmiXJRTuRMjly1r?p=catalogue